# How do i sort this data based on key value "name" using loops

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

```
'**data**': [
    {'name': 'Google', 'site_id': 31, 'new': 18, 'unique': 22, 'loyal': 4},
    {'name': 'mirav', 'site_id': 29, 'new': 9, 'unique': 15, 'loyal': 6},
    {'name': 'site1', 'site_id': 28, 'new': 10, 'unique': 18, 'loyal': 8},
    {'name': 'site3', 'site_id': 30, 'new': 14, 'unique': 23, 'loyal': 9},
    {'name': 'site5', 'site_id': 32, 'new': 19, 'unique': 22, 'loyal': 3},
    {'name': 'site6', 'site_id': 33, 'new': 16, 'unique': 18, 'loyal': 2},
    {'name': 'site7', 'site_id': 34, 'new': 13, 'unique': 14, 'loyal': 1},
    {'name': 'site8', 'site_id': 35, 'new': 17, 'unique': 20, 'loyal': 3},
    {'name': 'site91', 'site_id': 43, 'new': 21, 'unique': 27, 'loyal': 6},
    {'name': 'site92', 'site_id': 44, 'new': 35, 'unique': 39, 'loyal': 4}
]
```

Comment: this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value) may help

Comment: @AnkushRathi seems like above question is to sort items of list, not items of dictionary. the second link posted by "ilja-everilä" would be the solution. :)